# Extract parameters from a URL and pass them to a database

Tags: java, php, web-services, jsp

Assuming that I'm not concerned about the security aspect of this, a client computer calls the url:

```
myurl.com/file.ext?Param1=value&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

I then want to do a simple insert into a database

```
Insert into myDB(Col1, Col2, Col3)VALUES(Param1, Param2, Param3)
```

I will be doing my own char stripping on the input, I just can't find anything succinct on how to do this.

Comment: `I will be doing my own char stripping on the input` Don't. Do. That. Period. There are tools for that! Do never be `not concerned about the security aspect`. Even if it is only running on an isolated computer 100 feet under in a concrete sarcophagus...

Comment: Computer is running on an intranet, the url will be accessed via login scripts only.

Comment: it is possible to really _accidentally_ paste a string having a '; DROP TABLES; in there... I really mean accidental error!

Comment: The website is not public, and I'm going to be using a library to strip out all the characters (hence why I saw doing it on my own, before someone got concerned).  This url will likely NEVER be called by anything but the program, but I am covering my bases, I always do.   thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See  [URL.getQuery()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getQuery%28%29) 
It will return the query part of the url, and then use this method

```
URl u = new URL("myurl.com/file.ext?Param1=value&param2=value2&param3=value3");
Map<String, String> params = getQueryMap(u.getQuery());

public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query)  
{  
    String[] params = query.split("&");  
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    for (String param : params)  
    {  
        String[] parts = param.split("=");
        String name = parts[0];  
        String value = parts[1];  
        map.put(name, value);  
    }  
    return map;  
}
```

now you'll have all the parameters in the map, accessible. Format and execute the query using [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Comment: Awesome answer, I regret that I only have a single upvote to give.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "myurl.com/file.ext?Param1=value&param2=value2&param3=value3";
    int index = s.indexOf("Param1");
    String ss = s.substring(index);
    String[] arr = ss.split("&");
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        String[] value= arr[i].split("=");//value[i] will be value i+1th value
    }
```